# React Table, show the data from accessor, custom rendering from another column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have a bit of an interesting problem, I am new to  ([React-Table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table)) and I have a requirement I am unsure how to fulfill.

I want the `txName` to render so that it shows the value of the txName column, however on click of the cell, I want to redirect to the value of the `txId` column which is hidden.

So far this is what I have, I am hoping to use `fgpBinder` to tell react-table which column to use.

**The columns I am passing through.**

```
"dumbColumns": [
  { accessor: "icpNumber", Header: "ICP", minWidth: 210 },
  { accessor: "icpStatus", Header: "Status", minWidth: 180 },
  { accessor: "lvCircuit", Header: "LV Circuit", minWidth: 120 },
  { accessor: "txId", fgpBinder: "txName", label: "txName" , Header:"Transformer", id : "txId", minWidth : 140 },
  { accessor: "txName", fgpBinder: "txId" , label: "txId" , Header:"Transformer", id: "txId", minWidth: 140, show: false },
  { accessor: "txRating", Header: "Transformer Rating", minWidth: 80 },
  { accessor: "fdrId", Header: "Feeder", minWidth: 180 },
  { accessor: "zsId", Header: "Zone Substation", minWidth: 180 },
  { accessor: "gxpId", Header: "GXP", minWidth: 140 },
  { accessor: "anzsic", Header: "anzsic", minWidth: 100 },
  { accessor: "address", Header: "ICP Address", minWidth: 410 }
];
```

Code I have tried, I am getting back the `txName` and `txId` data in the log

```
buildData(data){
  data.forEach(element => {
    console.log(element)
  });
  return data;
}
```

The function here works and populates the cell with the value "txData" however I want the value of `txdata`

```
buildColumns(data){
  data.forEach(element => {
    if(element["fgpBinder"]){
      console.log(element)
      element["Cell"] = row => (
        <span>{element.fgpBinder}</span>
      )
    }
    // element["Cell"] = row => (
    //   <a href="https://www.google.com">
    //   CLICK ME
    //   </a>
    // )
  });
  return data;
}
```

For example the txName could be `foo`
and the txId could be `www.bah.com`

I would like to show `foo` but when i click the cell, be redirected to `www.bah.com`

Answer (score 0):

To deal with a column that has a specific behavior, you need to add to your column property the props `Cell`, in which you specify how to render your value.

To show the column with header `Transformer` with the `txName` value and the link `txId`, initialize your column like this:

```
buildColumns (columns) {
  let finalColumns = [];
  finalColumns = columns.map(column => {
    let finalColumn = {
      Header: column.Header,
      accessor: column.accessor,
      label: column.label,
      id: column.id,
      minWidth: column.minWidth,
      show: column.show
    }
    // CASE : fgpBinder exists, which implies a special Cell content
    if (column.fgpBinder) {
        finalColumn.Cell = (row) => (
          <a href={row.original[column.fgpBinder]}>{row.value}</a>
        );
    }
    return finalColumn;  
  });

  return finalColumns;
}
```

This is a generic columns construction. If you want to specify only the column with Header `Transformer`, you just need to initialize the column like this:

```
{
  Header: "Transformer",
  id: "txId",
  accessor: "txName",
  Cell: row => <a href={row.original.txId}>{row.value}</a>,
  fgpBinder: "txId",
  label: "txId",
  minWidth: 140,
}
```

Comment: I actually got this working, however I will test your method and let you know if it satisfied my question so I can give you internet points :D